# Bulit-in Windows 10 modern app Mail and Calendar downloads mail from Gmail with a long delay

Tags: windows-10, email, gmail, modern-ui

I'm using the latest, updated Win 10 with the latest Mail and Calendar app. For some time now, the app downloads new emails from Gmail with a ~2 hour delay.

To fix this, I tried resetting the app to the defaults and reinstalling and setting it up again, but to no avail. Also, the app has been set to download new emails immediately.

I noticed in Process Explorer that the Windows apps HxTsr.exe & HxOutlook.exe, which I think are associated with downloading mail, are in a suspended state. Maybe this is the problem? In Windows Modern Settings app I've got the Mail app allowed to run in background.

When I open the Mail app manually, it catches up and downloads new emails immediately.

At Gmail, I've got POP3 and IMAP activated and I haven't changed any settings there that would break the Mail app.

Comment: If you manually check your inbox before 2 hours as elapsed does the client download emails you have received?

Comment: @Ramhound If I check manually the emails download just fine.

Comment: There is either an option within the Mail UWP application or there is a scheduled task that happens ever 2 hours.  The state of the application is not connected to the 2 hour delay.

Comment: The app is set within to download new emails immediately. I went through the whole Windows Scheduler but I can't find there anything related to the mail app.